# Linux audio software to make old-time radio more understandable

Tags: linux, audio-editing

I love listening to old time radio (OTR) broadcasts collected from the internet.  The sound quality is often distorted so as to be not-comprehensible.  I listen on pretty modern LG TV (using internal speakers) with YouTube running the OTR media.  Mostly male voices get distorted; female voices are understandable.  I don't believe low fidelity/understandability issue is caused by LG sound settings or YouTube sounds settings as other tape broadcasts are heard well with distinct sound.  OTR media is the exception.

What Linux software could be used to clear up (make more distinct) voices on vinyl (I think) recordings from 30s, 40s, and 50s?  Also, any tips on how best to do this would be appreciated.

Comment: You can't convert low quality to high quality as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be very tempted to throw one or two at Adobe's new 'Podcast Enhance' & see what it makes of them.
It's still in Beta, but I've had it rescue some quite abysmal recordings recently, including one heavily reverberant & resonant; another that you could barely tell there was even any speech because of the noise. It's not particularly fast - seems to be about real-time - but I've never given it anything much over a minute as yet.

https://podcast.adobe.com/enhance#
Sign-up required, but free to use.

*Late Edit*
Actually, I just tried it on an old radio show, mainly spoken word but some musical interjections, in stereo.
It really made quite a mess of it… though it did only take 5 minutes to make a mess of a half-hour show, which it delivered in mono.
I think it's going to only handle 'one voice' spoken word, not panel show.
I'll leave this answer up to save anyone else having to go to the trouble of testing it.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts.  Podcast Enhance is a software I was unaware off.  Perhaps that will lead to other software.

Comment: Welcome. It does work remarkably well for 'single voice, just talking'… as I suppose is all they really claim as a podcast editor. It doesn't cope well with music, stereo spread of multiple panel members + audience sounds.

Comment: BTW, "industry standard" for this type of thing is Izotope RX - but expensive & I don't think runs on nix, Mac & Win only, iirc.